# TTS and play sound - Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, text-to-speech

I've a viewpager in my application. When the user swipes to the right/left I use TTS engine to speak the text and MediaPlayer to play a sound.

The problem is both plays simultaneously.. How do I play the sound once TTS engine speaks the text is over?

P.S: I don't want to use sleep or wait.

Update:

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        } else {
            //Do Something here
        }


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  >= 15 ){
            UtteranceProgressListener listener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //start MediaPlayer
                    playMedia(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                }
            };
            tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(listener);
        }
        else{
            tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String arg0) {
                     playMedia(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                }

              });
        }
    } else {
        Intent installIntent = new Intent();
        installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code you're using now ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to give it an id param. Otherwise it doesn't call the listeners:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");

textToSpeech.speak(string,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very useful for me! I would give you 5 vote ups if I could.

Answer (score 2):

In android their are two **APIs** to detect if the **TTS** engine finished speaking:

- **> Android 4 (ICS)**

  ```
  UtteranceProgressListener listener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {

      @Override
      public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onError(String utteranceId) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          //start MediaPlayer
      }
  };
      yourTTSObject.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(listener);
  ```
- **Perior to ICS Android 4.0** you can use :

  ```
  yourTTSObject.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener(){

      @Override
      public void onUtteranceCompleted(String arg0) {
            // start your mediaplayer here
      }

    });
  ```

  take a look at the documentations [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I tried using your code.. but it doesn't work. Please check my updated question (I've pasted the code for your reference).

Comment: I've been using such code on many projects for long time now and tested on so many devices. so for example try to trace code excution ( by using break points or logcat ) and see how it goes.